# proving (angle-side-longer-side congruence)

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, euclidean-geometry

consider ∆ABC and ∆DEF such that ∠A ≅ ∠D, (AB) ̅ ≅  (DE) ̅, (BC) ̅≅ (EF) ̅ and assume in addition that (BC) ̅ ≥ (AB) ̅ Then ∆ABC ≅ ∆DEF

What I have so far:

if (BC) ̅ = (AB) ̅  then by isosceles triangle theorem ∠ A ≅ ∠ C. Which means by transitive property ∠A ≅ ∠C ≅ ∠D ≅ ∠F. Then by AAS congruence ∆ABC ≅ ∆DEF. If segment (BC) ̅  > (AB) ̅  then we can construct a perpendicular bisector from vertex B that intersects  (AC) ̅ at point X with ∠BXA and ∠BXC being right angles. With  (AB) ̅ ≅ (DE) ̅, ∠A ≅ ∠D and ∠AXB ≅ ∠DXE then ∆ABX ≅ ∆DEX by AAS congruence. With (BC) ̅ ≅  (EF) ̅, ∠A ≅ ∠D, and ∠CXB ≅ ∠FYE then ∆BCX ≅ ∆FEY by AAS congruence. Then by congruence and betweenness theorem for points (AX) ̅ ≅  (DY) ̅, (XC) ̅ ≅ (YF) ̅,
by substitution AX + XC = AC and DY + YF = DF then AC ≅ DF then by SSS congruence ∆ ABC ≅ ∆ DEF

this is the line I'm stuck with:

If segment (BC) ̅  > (AB) ̅  then we can construct a perpendicular bisector from vertex B that intersects  (AC) ̅ at point X with ∠BXA and ∠BXC being right angles.

I don't know if I can actually construct this bisector from the vertex, since this bisector may not exist on every triangle, and if I can't then the rest of my proof is thrown out the window. So I need some confirmation on if this holds on every triangle and if it doesn't I could definitely use some helping proving these two triangles are congruent. Thanks

Comment: The foot of altitude $X$ from $B$ to $AC$ may be outside the segment $AC$, for example when $\angle A$ is obtuse. (And $BX$ is still not a perpendicular bisector)

Answer (score 1):

Consider $\triangle DEG \cong \triangle ABC$. As $\angle GDE \cong \angle FDE \cong \angle CAB$, so $G$ lies on ray $DF$. Length $EG=EF=BC$. Suppose that $G$ is not coincident with $F$. Let $H$ to be middle of $GF$. Triangle $EGF$ is isosceles, then $EH$ is altitude. Points $F$ and $G$ are at different sides from $H$, that's why one of these points lies between $H$ and $D$. Mark this point as $I$. I don't know which facts you can use for prove, but using Pythagoras theorem or the fact that the longest side in a triangle is opposite the largest angle, you can prove that length of $DE$ is greater than $IE=BC$, which contradicts condition $BC > AB$.